# Comments make me so confused: confessions of a bash shell script noob

Tags: bash, shell, comments

When I run this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check_foo () {
    if [ -n "$foo" ];
    then
      echo "foo exists: $foo" 
      echo ""
    else 
      echo "no foo"
      echo ""
    fi
} 


echo "foo="
foo=
check_foo

echo "foo=#wtf"
foo=#wtf
check_foo

echo "foo=# wtf"
foo=# wtf
check_foo

echo "foo= #wtf"
foo= #wtf
check_foo

echo 'foo="wtf"'
foo="wtf"
check_foo

echo 'foo=#"wtf"'
foo=#"wtf"
check_foo

echo 'foo=# "wtf"'
foo=# "wtf"
check_foo

echo 'foo= # "wtf"'
foo= # "wtf"
check_foo
```

I get this output:

```
foo=
no foo

foo=#wtf
foo exists: #wtf

foo=# wtf
./wtf.sh: line 24: wtf: command not found
foo exists: #wtf

foo= #wtf
no foo

foo="wtf"
foo exists: wtf

foo=#"wtf"
foo exists: #wtf

foo=# "wtf"
./wtf.sh: line 40: wtf: command not found
foo exists: #wtf

foo= # "wtf"
no foo
```

I expected the shell to stop reading after the '#'. Could someone explain?

**Edit**

I should have phrased my question more carefully. I understand *what* is happening. What I do not understand is *why* you would want a comment that works this way. Is there some advantage to this behavior? Or is it just an artifact of the way the shell processes arguments?

Answer (score 1):

No that's not true. For any line to be a comment `#` needs to be at line start OR after some white-spaces only on a line.

So for example this won't be a comment and a valid variable assignment in shell:

```
s=#123
echo "$s"
#123
```

Comment: Yes. Also, note that in e.g. `foo=# wtf`, the space is taken as a separator between an assignment and the command it applies to -- that is, it tries to execute the command `wtf` with foo set to "#", which fails because `wtf` isn't a valid command.

Comment: Yes that's right, thanks @GordonDavisson for clarifying about that.